# Laravel 5.8 - How to move file from storage directory to public directory?

Tags: php, laravel, file-storage

I would like to move one of my files from the `storage` file directory in Laravel to the `public` file directory in laravel, without changing my file system configuration. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with [Storage::move](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files) and [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-public-path) helper.

`Storage::move( 'old/file.jpg', public_path('new/file.jpg') );`

Note that `old/file.jpg` is relative to `your-project/storage/app`, so the file that you want to move would be in `your-project/storage/app/old/file.jpg`

---

UPDATE

Still, another approach could be to move/store the file in `laravel-project/storage/app/public`.

And then have it accessible in the public directory via a [symbolic link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk).

After that, all the files and directories inside `laravel-project/storage/app/public` will be linked to `laravel-project/public/storage/` directory.
Then you can access the file by url.

So, to do it in this way, move the file to storage/app/public/ folder:

```
Storage::move( 'old/file.jpg', 'public/movedfiles/file.jpg' );
```

Create the symbolic link by this artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then you can access the file by url:

```
<a href='http://your-domain/storage/movedfiles/file.jpg'>file.jpg</a>
```

or in blade

```
<a href='{{ asset('storage/movedfiles/file.jpg') }}'>file.jpg</a>
```

Comment: If it is stored in the /storage/public/ folder is it still accessible by everyone? Is there any solution where I can make my files protected?

Comment: @AidenKaiser  Your files are protected in the storage directory. The whole directory `storage/app/public` will be linked, the files will not be directly in the public directory, only its representation through the link, but the link will be publicly accessible, so everyone can read it. If you want  make files not publicly accessible move them to another directory, for example `storage/app/files`.