# Laravel Storage - Move Images 1 folder

Tags: laravel, storage

I want to move all images up 1 folder after which I can remove the empty folder but I always get the error "File already exists at path: public/images"

```
$files = Storage::files('public/images/'.$dir->name);
   foreach($files as $file){
     Storage::move($file, 'public/images');
   }
   Storage::deleteDirectory('public/images/'.$dir->name);
   $dir->delete();
```

The files that I wanted to remove don't exist in the public/images directory. So why do I get the error "File already exists at path: public/images"?

Comment: you want to remove the folder which saves the image? and why would you want to do that?

Comment: Your source and target location are the same. This should get you going:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814137/laravel-5-8-how-to-move-file-from-storage-directory-to-public-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
$files = Storage::files('public/images/'.$dir->name);
foreach($files as $file){
  Storage::move($file, 'public/images/'.basename($file));
}
Storage::deleteDirectory('public/images/'.$dir->name);
$dir->delete();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it! Didn't know the filename must be attached to the destination path